# Should this "translation" question be accepted as-is, or split up?

Tags: discusión, ámbito

While I think this question is an excellent use of our resources as a community, I wonder if it's truly on-topic *as written*:

- https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3241/12

The question is essentially "Translate this stack of ancient texts."  Although translation (to/from other languages) is expressly off-topic in our FAQ:

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> ...
>
> - Languages other than Spanish (including translation)

the FAQ doesn't say anything about large-scale translation from old-Spanish to new-Spanish.

And my feeling is that it ought to be on topic; this is precisely the type of question that ought to attract experts, right?

I am, however, concerned, that the question is **too large**.  As it's written, it will not serve very well as a resource to future visitors.

This followup question (which was apparently asked before the original question was migrated from History.SE) is a much better fit, I believe:

- [Translating a text from the XV century to modern Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3239/12)

Although even that could be easily split into at least two questions, I believe:

1. What is the meaning of "provança"?
2. What is the meaning of "dho/dhos"?
3. Possibly, Why is "Su" used in this context?

By splitting the question into smaller chunks like this it becomes a much more useable resource for others.

How does the community feel about this?

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. It should be split up!